# inserting data into tables that share foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables that require insertion from a single form.

Table1 - `user_info(user_id(primary), full_name, username, user_password, email)`

Table 2 - `user_personal_info(user_id(foreign), username(foreign), full_name(foreign), user_profession, user_phone, age)`

The `user_id` is auto-increment.

I am trying to take the information received on the register form and insert them into each table. However, the first table takes all the information and the second one does not. I've tried doing two separate inserts with no success.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
$password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_profession = NULL;
$user_phone = NULL;
$age = NULL;

$query_user_info = $connection -> prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE EMAIL=:email");
$query_user_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_user_info->execute();

if ($query_user_info-> rowCount() > 0) {
    echo '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>';
}

if ($query_user_info-> rowCount() == 0) {
    $query_user_info = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(full_name,username,user_password,email) VALUES (:full_name, :username, :password_hash,:email)");
    $query_user_info->bindParam("full_name", $full_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("password_hash", $password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result = $query_user_info->execute();

    $query_user_personal_info = $connection->prepare ("INSERT INTO user_personal_info(user_id,full_name, username, email, user_profession, user_phone, age) VALUES (:id, :full_name, :username, :email, :user_profession, :user_phone, :age)");
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("user_id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("full_name", $full_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("user_profession", $user_profession, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("user_phone", $user_phone, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("age", $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result2 = $query_user_personal_info->execute();

    if ($result) { // create a profile page.
        echo '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">Something went wrong!</p>';
    }


    if ($result2) { // create a profile page.
        echo '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">no bueno :(</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `$_SESSION['user_id']` exist if the user hasn't been added to the table? Do you receive errors with this code?

Comment: no errors, however that was my last attempt to finding a solution. clearly it isnt correct.

Comment: So you get `Your registration was successful!` twice? Do you have exceptions on?

Comment: first insertion is successful. the second prompt i get is no bueno

Comment: You are answering half my questions. `How does $_SESSION['user_id'] exist if the user hasn't been added to the table?` ... `Do you have exceptions on?` See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Please think about your DB, create some model, that you wanna store, then your PHP can talk to that to allow into the DB.. Make a filter.. All you have is a php mess of what comes in from forms. : Lookup how to use Interfaces. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php : `$query_user_info->bindParam("username` if you cant see that this is a problem '$connection -> prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE EMAIL=:email");' you need to find someone who does

Comment: When you say the second one does not, are you able to provide some more information? What is being inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be getting the inserted ID from the `user_info` table?

Try this

```php
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
$password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$user_profession = NULL;
$user_phone = NULL;
$age = NULL;

$query_user_info = $connection -> prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE EMAIL=:email");
$query_user_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_user_info->execute();

if ($query_user_info-> rowCount() > 0) {
    echo '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>';
}

if ($query_user_info-> rowCount() == 0) {
    $query_user_info = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(full_name,username,user_password,email) VALUES (:full_name, :username, :password_hash,:email)");
    $query_user_info->bindParam("full_name", $full_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("password_hash", $password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result = $query_user_info->execute();
    $id = $query_user_info->lastInsertId();

    $query_user_personal_info = $connection->prepare ("INSERT INTO user_personal_info(user_id,full_name, username, email, user_profession, user_phone, age) VALUES (:id, :full_name, :username, :email, :user_profession, :user_phone, :age)");
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("user_id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("full_name", $full_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("user_profession", $user_profession, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("user_phone", $user_phone, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("age", $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result2 = $query_user_personal_info->execute();

    if ($result) { // create a profile page.
        echo '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">Something went wrong!</p>';
    }


    if ($result2) { // create a profile page.
        echo '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">no bueno :(</p>';
    }
}
```

Also, are `$user_profession`, `$user_phone`, and `$age` required in your database? If not, then you don't need those values to insert into your table if they just default to null values.

Try changing it to this

```php
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
$password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$query_user_info = $connection -> prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE EMAIL=:email");
$query_user_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_user_info->execute();

if ($query_user_info-> rowCount() > 0) {
    echo '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>';
}

if ($query_user_info-> rowCount() == 0) {
    $query_user_info = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(full_name,username,user_password,email) VALUES (:full_name, :username, :password_hash,:email)");
    $query_user_info->bindParam("full_name", $full_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("password_hash", $password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result = $query_user_info->execute();
    $id = $query_user_info->lastInsertId();

    $query_user_personal_info = $connection->prepare ("INSERT INTO user_personal_info(user_id,full_name, username, email) VALUES (:id, :full_name, :username, :email)");
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("user_id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("full_name", $full_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_user_personal_info->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result2 = $query_user_personal_info->execute();

    if ($result) { // create a profile page.
        echo '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">Something went wrong!</p>';
    }


    if ($result2) { // create a profile page.
        echo '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error">no bueno :(</p>';
    }
}
```